# LibreOffice Calc issues converting from numeric to text

Tags: arcgis, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Running latest LibreOffice version 6.3.3.2 on Windows 10 Pro.
I have a csv file and attempting to convert a column from numeric to text. On text import screen, I choose the column "Tract_id" and choose column type = text as shown here [Text import screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLkQr.png). File then opens and all fields are converted to text EXCEPT the header cell "Tract_id". Attempted to import the csv file to a program called ArcGIS, but it detects column as numeric, I'm assuming due to the header cell still being numeric. I then manually converted the header cell to text via properties in LibreOffice Calc. ArcGIS still detects column as numeric. After reopening and closing the file in LibreOffice Calc, I once again get the text import screen (not sure why?) and have to choose the column as text again, so it just goes circles not getting anywhere. I need to get that column header cell to stay as text. Any input appreciated.

Comment: Hi vegan_renegade. By default Tract_id will be imported as a number as defined by the function TYPE() You can change this in the CSV import dialogue in libre office. To change the type in ARCgis this may help you https://community.esri.com/thread/209885-how-can-i-specify-the-data-types-for-the-columns-in-a-csv-i-upload

Comment: Hi pnorton...as stated in my post, I already choose the column "Tract_id" and choose column type = text. Can you elaborate what else I need to do in the import dialogue?

Comment: Hi  vegan_renegade. Did the link help you ? Ref ARCgis https://community.esri.com/thread/209885-how-can-i-specify-the-data-types-for-the-columns-in-a-csv-i-upload